# Passing JS variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, server

I am trying to pass a JS variable to PHP and have PHP echo the JS variable back.
I keep getting an empty null string. What am I doing wrong?

```
function(u){

            if(u){
                var dt = {'ud':u};
                console.log(dt);

                $.post('xrege.php', dt, function(r){
                    console.log(r.responseText);
                    console.log(typeof(r.responseText));
                });
            }
        });


<?php

$ud = $_POST['ud'];
echo json_encode($ud);
?>
```

Comment: Check what `r` is.

Comment: Thought r would be the response I received from the server

Comment: 1) `u` is a boolean in this case. 2) You're trying to asign `u` to nothing. The correct syntax would be `{ud: u}` without the quotes. Quote from the jQuery api: `$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );` 3) Don't mix Javascript with jQuery. It should be `console.log(r);`

Comment: u is a variable that should have a value, I just want to check if indeed it does have a value before passing it to the server. I spent two hours scratching my head and overlooked the syntax error though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should separate php code into a different file and it should be working.

```
if(u){
    var dt = {'ud':u};
    console.log(dt);

    $.post('xrege.php', dt, function(r){
        console.log(r);
        console.log(typeof r);
    },"json");
}
```

name the above code like 123.html and keep the below code in xrege.php

```
<?php
$ud = $_POST['ud'];
echo json_encode($ud);
?>
```

Comment: The code is already segregated. I am using two other PHP files that work perfectly well. But for the life of me, I cannot even get the most basic response from this one.