# define javascript variable from php variable within php code

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to define javascript variable from php variable in the running php code.

Here is my code:

```
echo "<script>"; 
echo "var s1 = '<?php echo isset($s1) ? $s1 : ''  ?>';";
echo "getAirdrop();";
echo "</script>";
```

But this code not defining the javascript variable.

Comment: You're already in a PHP block. Adding `<?php` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing JS variable to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569761/passing-js-variable-to-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need php tags again.

Try it like this:

```php
echo "<script>";
echo "var s1 = '";
echo isset($s1) ? $s1 : '';
echo "';";
echo "getAirdrop();";
echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line, just concatenate all yours echo :

```
echo "<script> let s1 = ".isset($s1) ? $s1 : ''." getAirdrop(); </script>"
```